# Is it possible to use Web Sockets with Apple Watch? For example using Starscream

Tags: swift, websocket, apple-watch, watchos, starscream

Does Apple Watch support Web Sockets? Is it possible to use an external library like Starscream? https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried and yesss it works!!! Apple Watch supports Web Sockets ;)

**EDIT:**

It doesn't work anymore in WatchOS 6/6.1 :(

Go here for more info: [Why is Starscream not working anymore on real Apple Watch (WatchOS 6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290988/why-is-starscream-not-working-anymore-on-real-apple-watch-watchos-6)

Answer (score 2):

Starscream doesn't work with SSL on watchOS because it is missing ["the `kCFStream` properties"](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/e6b65c6d9077ea48b4a7bdda8994a1d3c6969c8d/Sources/Starscream/WebSocket.swift#L171)