# Why is Starscream not working anymore on real Apple Watch (WatchOS 6)?

Tags: swift, websocket, apple-watch, starscream, watchos-6

Recently I upgraded my Apple Watch to WatchOS 6.0.1, my iPhone to iOS 13.1.2, Xcode to 11.1. MacOS still 10.14.6.

I've created an Independent Apple Watch project where I test the communication between the Watch and a WebSocket server using Starscream: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

It **works perfectly on the Simulator** but on **real Apple Watch** when I try to connect to the server I **got these errors**:

```
2019-10-08 18:57:53.064887+0200 BackgroundWebSocketOnlyWatch WatchKit Extension[251:31011] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C1] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection

2019-10-08 18:57:53.068928+0200 BackgroundWebSocketOnlyWatch WatchKit Extension[251:31011] TCP Conn 0x16d8d5f0 Failed : error 0:50 [50]

websocket is disconnected: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. Network is down")
```

I'll show you the code of my app:

**InterfaceController.swift**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import Starscream

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WebSocketDelegate {

let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://echo.websocket.org/")!)

@IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

/**************************************************************************************************/

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    socket.delegate = self
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

/************************************************************************************************/

@IBAction func connectButtonPressed() {

    socket.connect()
}

@IBAction func sendButtonPressed() {

    socket.write(string: "Hi!")
}

@IBAction func disconnectButtonPressed() {

    socket.disconnect()
}

/******************************************************************************************/

func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
    print("websocket is connected")
    label.setText("Connected")
}
func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
    print("websocket is disconnected: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    label.setText("Disconnected")
}
func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
    print("got some text: \(text)")
    label.setText("Received: \(text)")
    createVibration()

}
func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
    print("got some data: \(data.count)")
}
/******************************************************************************************/

// Creates vibration
func createVibration() {

    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.notification)
    print("Vibration created")
}
```

}

I tried using **Starscream** with **iOS 13.1.2** and it **works perfectly both on Simulator and real iPhone**.

Is this a **bug** of WatchOS 6 or is Starscream that needs an upgrade?

Thanks in advance! :)

---

**EDIT:** 5th November 2019

I've updated my Apple Watch to WatchOS 6.1 and iPhone to iOS 13.2 and WebSocket still doesn't work on the watch...

Got some new errors though:

```
2019-11-05 12:33:29.317757+0100 BackgroundWebSocketBothDevices WatchKit Extension[269:37201] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:4 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted

2019-11-05 12:33:29.317919+0100 BackgroundWebSocketBothDevices WatchKit Extension[269:37201] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked [C1] DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)

2019-11-05 12:33:29.319083+0100 BackgroundWebSocketBothDevices WatchKit Extension[269:37255] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C1] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection

2019-11-05 12:33:29.319150+0100 BackgroundWebSocketBothDevices WatchKit Extension[269:37255] TCP Conn 0x155a7360 Failed : error 0:-65563 [-65563]

websocket is disconnected: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -72000.)
```

Answer (score 1):

WatchOS us unfortunately is missing the kCFStream properties to make this work.

https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/e6b65c6d9077ea48b4a7bdda8994a1d3c6969c8d/Sources/Starscream/WebSocket.swift#L171